# Python PyQt5 webview can't open tabs created with no url

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebview

Trying to parse a web site with pyqt5.My problem is that a tab created by this page isn't a link but a button creating the tab with a onclick function, so when i use the linkClicked signal nothing happens.The generated tab is the one i want to parse.

All examples i find online opens tabs with links so i cant get throught this.

P.S. I know Qwebkit is predicated but i must use this to be windows xp compatible.

What i have:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView , QWebPage
from PyQt5 import QtWebKit
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import QWebSettings
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import *
import sys




class MainForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self)        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabWidget)        
        self.loadUrl(QtCore.QUrl('https://www.notams.faa.gov/dinsQueryWeb/'))

    def loadUrl(self, url):    
        self.view = QWebView()  
        self.view.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.view.linkClicked.connect(self.on_linkClicked)
        self.view.loadStarted.connect(self.on_url_changed)
        self.view.page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(QWebPage.DelegateAllLinks)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(self.tabWidget.addTab(self.view, 'loading...'))
        self.view.load(url)

    def _on_load_finished(self, ok):
        index = self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.sender())
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(index, self.sender().url().host())
        self.view.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();")
        self.view.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByName('retrieveLocId')[0].value='%s';"%('lgel lgal lggg'))
        self.view.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByName('submit')[0].click();")

    def on_linkClicked(self, url):        
        self.loadUrl(url)

    def on_url_changed(self):
        print('xdddd')



def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to parse the other page, why are you loading the first? Can't you just send a post request to the target ( https://www.notams.faa.gov/dinsQueryWeb/queryRetrievalMapAction.do )?

Comment: No the generated page is blank.It needs to generate the data from the first page

Comment: No, it does not, you have to add the network request parameters and fields to the url. Btw, it seems that the page also supports GET methods, so you can just load this: [https://www.notams.faa.gov/dinsQueryWeb/queryRetrievalMapAction.do?reportType=Report&retrieveLocId=lgel%20lgal%20lggg&actionType=notamRetrievalByICAOs](https://www.notams.faa.gov/dinsQueryWeb/queryRetrievalMapAction.do?reportType=Report&retrieveLocId=lgel%20lgal%20lggg&actionType=notamRetrievalByICAOs); note that the "retrieveLocId" has your keywords separated by urlencoded spaces: "lgel lgal lggg" becomes "lgel%20lgal%20lggg"

Comment: I am a noob on webpages , thank you.I will leave this if anyone can solve the redirect issue but you solved my problem.Best regards.

Comment: You're welcome! I added the answer to the question, even if it wasn't your actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a page requests to create a new window, [`createWindow(WebWindowType)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#createWindow) is called; if the method does not return a new QWeb[Engine]View (or is not implemented, the default) a similar method is called on the view; again, if it's not implemented, nothing happens.

If you want to load the new window in the same one it was requested, just override the WebView and return `self`, and enable the support for opening new windows from javascript:

```
class SelfishWebView(QWebView):
    def createWindow(self, windowType):
        return self


class MainForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def loadUrl(self, url):    
        self.view = SelfishWebView()  
        self.view.page().settings().setAttribute(
            QWebSettings.JavascriptCanOpenWindows, True)
        # ...
```

Note that if you execute the javascript like that, it will try to recursively call again as soon as the new page is loaded (and, since there is a button in that new page, it will try to click it); you should disconnect the signal as soon as it is loaded the first time.

```
    def _on_load_finished(self, ok):
        self.view.loadFinished.disconnect(self._on_load_finished)
        # ...
```